# C# MSChart : Bars are colored only the first time

Tags: c#, charts

To show Candlebars on Chart I use this code and it works fine. When I scroll the `chart1.Series["SerieVolume"]` has the default series color.
Can you explain me please what to do, so that the bars are painted with the good color every time?

```
private void DrawBarre(int no)
{
   chart1.Series["SerieBougie"].Points.AddXY(no,Glob.Barres[no].High, Glob.Barres[no].Low,
       Glob.Barres[no].Open, Glob.Barres[no].Close);
   chart1.Series["SerieVolume"].Points.AddXY(no, Glob.Barres[no].Volume);
   chart1.Series["SerieIndic1"].Points.AddXY(no, Glob.Barres[no].Volume);
   chart1.Series["SerieIndic1_100"].Points.AddXY(no, Glob.Barres[no].Volume);
   chart1.Series["SerieIndic2"].Points.AddXY(no, Glob.Barres[no].Volume);
   chart1.Series["SerieIndic2_100"].Points.AddXY(no, Glob.Barres[no].Volume);
   if ( Glob.Barres[no].Open >  Glob.Barres[no].Close)
   {
       chart1.Series["SerieVolume"].Points[no].Color = System.Drawing.Color.MistyRose;
   }
   else
   {
       chart1.Series["SerieVolume"].Points[no].Color = System.Drawing.Color.PaleTurquoise;
   }
   hScrollBar1.Maximum = Glob.Barres.Count - Zoom.val;
}
```

Comment: A DataPoint does not change its color(s) just by being scrolled. When is `DrawBarre` being scrolled?

Comment: Like many beginners alas, I was looking to reinvent the wheel by wanting to make my own scrolling system while it is integrated. I use it and everything is correct. Thank you for taking the time to answer me